# How to frame URL with username and password to access Rest API using basic authentication Java?

Tags: java, spring, restful-authentication, restful-url

I have developed Rest API basic authentication, I am able to get the JSON response only when I test using Advanced Rest Client plugin(for Chrome), But how to access the JSON response by passing username and password in URL? How can others consume my rest API? Do I need to give any login popup? How can I achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your method should be `POST` and you need to create a `encripted token` for every login, and you need to active that token up to user logged out or anything else, you can store that token in browser cache, when user logged out then remove that token as well. for every user action you need to verify that token. you can generate token using `MD5` also.

i think it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How other application can consume this rest service? How can they give username and password?

Comment: are you talking about other application, like the application which have no login functionality , right?